# Java deserialization of generic type with Gson

Tags: java, generics, deserialization, gson

I'm trying to deserialize some generic type. It works nice, but I would like to swap this piece of code out to a method.

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<TestResult<MyObject>>(){}.getType();
TestResult<MyObject> result = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
```

How to I do this, proving information about the type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.
The type of a generics can't be determinted during runtime.

An easy workaround would be to add a method to `MyObject` to return the resulting Type (like the first line of your code sample).

Comment: And if I just want to provide MyObject type as parameter? Basically move the following code to a method: 

Type listType = new TypeToken<TestResult<X>>(){}.getType();
TestResult<X> result = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);

Does this work?

Comment: I guess `listType` could be determined from `MyObject.getType()`, but unfortuantely I don't know how.

Comment: Please see the below answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. There is a workaround.
You just have to explicitly pass the type and class of "MyObject" to the method.

In your case, develop a method having the following signature and body.

```
public <T> Object getGenericDataObjectFromJson(String json, Type t, Class<T> type) {

        // Convert Json String to Java object
         TestResult<T> obj = gson.fromJson(json, t);

        return obj;
    }
```

Where

1. String json = your json string
2. Type listType = your listType object passed as a parameter
3. Class type = MyObject.class

And the method call would become like this

```
GsonUtility gs = new GsonUtility();// Your gson utility class
JSONObject jsonObj = "your json string";

// Explicitly identifying the type so as to pass it to the method
// Because The type of a generics can't be determinted during runtime as #CKuk said

Type objectType = new TypeToken<DataObject<objectType>>(){}.getType();

TestResult<MyObject> resultObject= (TestResult<MyObject>) gs.getGenericDataObjectFromJson(jsonObj.toString(), objectType, MyObject.class);
```